# Using Parallel.ForEach in WCF service is returning TimeOut Error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

We have a wcf service(let's say WCF Service A) which gets invoked from Windows Service.

In WCF Service A, we are using Parallel.ForEach to create 5 threads to execute the same Method (say Method A)

This Method A has a call to Method B in WCF Service B and Method B has a call to Method C in WCF Service C and Method C has a call to Method D in WCF Service D.

Now issue is, call to Method D in WCF Service D is timing out in Method C of WCF Service C. I somehow removed call to Method D in Method C, but now Call to Method C is timing out in Method B of WCF Service B.

ServiceThrottling is under limits and no deadlocks are seen in DB.

Same code works when the list passed to Parallel.ForEach has only one item.

Comment: What operation is taking so long that it causes the timeout? What work is the slow service doing? Since you are querying the DB on multiple connections SQL Server can't detect deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is with Operating System, i am running this on Windows 7 which is crossing the thread limit set in IIS. When i moved this to Windows Server 2008, no time out issue observed.